# how would I organize this listbox in this python gui?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-datetime

I have made a code where u type your name, birth year, month, day , and weather you're a male or a female and each answer will be listed into a listbox. whats below is an image of my gui[image of my gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNnSv.png)

the problem is that when i put in the age of someone that is 13 and the age of someoe that is 15, the listbox won't organize the ages from oldest to youngest.

this us what my code looks like

```
from cmath import e
from tkinter import*
from datetime import date
from tkinter import messagebox
one = Tk()
one.title("NICE")
one.state("zoomed")
today = date.today()




clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set("Male")
def adi():
    a.insert(END, three.get())
def gen():
    if clicked.get() == "Male":
        b.insert(END, three.get())
    else:
        c.insert(END, three.get())
def age():
    d= int(birth_day.get())
    m=int(birth_month.get())
    y=int(birth_year.get())
    age = today.year-y-((today.month, today.day)<(m,d))
    d1.insert(END, age)

two = [
"Male",
"Female"
]


frame = Frame(one)
frame.pack(pady=5)

lf = Frame(frame)
lf.pack(pady=5)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Name")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

a = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
a.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Male")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

b = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
b.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Female")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

c = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
c.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH,padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Age")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

d1 = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
d1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

frame2 = Frame(one)
frame2.pack(pady=20)


three = Entry(frame2, font=("Futura", 30))
three.pack(pady=20)


age1 = Frame(frame2)
age1.pack(pady=10)

lbf = Frame(age1)
lbf.pack()

Label(lbf, text="Birth Year", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=150)
Label(lbf, text="Birth Month", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=120)
Label(lbf, text="Birth Date", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=150)

yearvalue = StringVar()
monthvalue = StringVar()
dayvalue = StringVar()

birth_year = Entry(age1, textvariable=yearvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birth_year.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)

birth_month = Entry(age1, textvariable=monthvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birth_month.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)

birth_day = Entry(age1, textvariable=dayvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birth_day.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)

drop = OptionMenu(frame2, clicked, *two ).pack(pady=10)   
add = Button(frame2, text="Submit", command=lambda:[adi(), gen(), age()]).pack()




#LABEL/BUTTON

one.mainloop()
```

could someone help me figure out what i should add to make this work?

Comment: I think it would be easiest for you to store the values in a `list` and then you can call the `sorted()` method on the list before you add them to your listbox.

Comment: Suggest to use `ttk.Treeview` widget instead of 4 listboxes.

Comment: You can go through the age listbox to find the insertion position and then add the other information at this insertion position in other listboxes.